# Cartoon movie / show with evil woman killing a woman and turning into a black blob on a castle

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It’s a older cartoon movie (maybe late 90s early 00s), I want to say like *Quest for Camelot*, except I have a distinct memory of the evil person (I think Morgana, but not sure) killing a girl/woman and then turning into a black blob. This all took place on top of an open castle. The other most important part is I distinctly remember them saying “she’s dead, she’s dead, poor thing she’s dead” in a sing song voice after they killed her

Comment: Also I know it’s very vague, but it’s been in the back of my mind for years and really bugs me.